# cumsum data over time by factor

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, cumsum

I'm using the campaign contributions data from Oregon and I'm trying to make a graph that displays the cumulative amount of contributions per candidate over time. Here's what I have so far:

```
ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(contb_receipt_dt, "%d-%b-%y"), 
           y = cumsum(contb_receipt_amt)),
           data = subset(oregon_data,
                      table(oregon_data$cand_nm)[oregon_data$cand_nm] > 1000                         
                          & as.Date(contb_receipt_dt, "%d-%b-%y") > as.Date("2015-01-01"))) 
+ geom_line(aes(color = cand_nm), bins = 5)
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: failed graph]

What I would like to see is a line for each candidate that starts off at 0 and slowly goes up with each additional contribution. What should I do?

Comment: Is this data open data? Do you have a URL or can you post a small sample?

Comment: I'm using the Oregon data at this URL: http://fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do

Answer (score 0):

I would use dplyr to calculate the `cumsum` column before sending it on to ggplot.  This should give you enough to get sarted, however you will need to pretty it up and filter the data to get the results you are looking for:

```
WashingtonData <- read.csv("P00000001-WA.csv")
WashingtonData <- WashingtonData %>% arrange(contb_receipt_dt)

MyGraphData <- WashingtonData %>% group_by(cand_nm) %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(contb_receipt_amt))

g <- ggplot(data=MyGraphData, aes(y=cumsum, x=contb_receipt_dt, color=cand_nm)) + geom_line()
g
```